# Im having an issue with setting a piece of javascript code as a background

Tags: javascript, background

I've just gotten started with coding on my new school, and I'm making a website as my first project. Now I'm trying to make this "matrix" animation appear as my background (made mostly in javascript), but I just cant get it to work. Could anyone help me with this issue? If it's even possible, that is. Thanks. (I know the code is kind of messy... first time posting, no idea how to do this)

HTML

```
<div class="inhoud">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="over_stuff">
      Here's some stuff over #pixie!
    </div>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  /*basic reset*/

  #container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #c {
    z-index: 0;
    background: #010222;
    background:
  }

  #over_stuff {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  /*adding a black bg to the body to make things clearer*/

  body {
    background: black;
  }

  canvas {
    display: block;
  }
```

Javascript

```
  var c = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  //making the canvas full screen
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  c.width = window.innerWidth;

  //chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
  var chinese = "dirk";
  //converting the string into an array of single characters
  chinese = chinese.split("");

  var font_size = 10;
  var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
  //an array of drops - one per column
  var drops = [];
  //x below is the x coordinate
  //1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
  for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    drops[x] = 1;

  //drawing the characters
  function draw() {
    //Black BG for the canvas
    //translucent BG to show trail
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#555"; //green text
    ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
    //looping over drops
    for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
      //a random chinese character to print
      var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random() * chinese.length)];
      //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
      ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

      //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
      //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
      if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
        drops[i] = 0;

      //incrementing Y coordinate
      drops[i]++;
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 33);
```

Comment: what is the problem you're having?  I just copied your code to jsfiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/9omp4f66/ -- and it appears to be working...

Comment: And looks cool as well!

Comment: @elijah Well, i want to have it as a background on my website. its not online right now, but if i would be to try posting it here all the code would get pretty messy. although i could send some pictures. What it looks like: https://postimg.org/image/ov515om0j/ what it is supposed to look like: https://postimg.org/image/ynflrbbib/. i want the piece of code to be the background, in place of the blue background.

Comment: If you want to see the full thing: http://paste.ofcode.org/Bq7QgZCTL8tYYjjTHEVvwW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT! all it took was to add
Postion:fixed to the code, and then give that a z-index of -10. thanks for taking the time to look at my code anyway ;)